# Apple, Banana, Pineapple problem

Tags: equation-solving

I'm attempting to solve:

```
 FindInstance[a/(b + p) + b/(a + p) + p/(a + b) == 4 && a > 0 && b > 0 && p > 0, {a, b, p}, Integers]
```

but, after evaluating in Mathematica, I get a message: "FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist."

Hint: Please, click on the following link:

[Elliptic functions](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4/answer/Alon-Amit)

Thank you!

Comment: Please change your title to one that is informative and helps others find this problem and the coming solutions.

Comment: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x/(y%2Bz)+%2B+y/(z%2Bx)+%2B+z/(x%2By)+%3D+4+over+the+integers&source=nav] W|A may help?

Comment: @David G. Stork - The title is fine.  This is how this particular problem is known.  "Equation-solving" also gives a hint about the problem's mathematical nomenclature.  @ Hans: A non-negative integer solution to the problem is: apple = 154476802108746166441951315019919837485664325669565431700026634898253202035277999; banana = 36875131794129999827197811565225474825492979968971970996283137471637224634055579; pineapple = 
4373612677928697257861252602371390152816537558161613618621437993378423467772036.

Comment: The title is absolutely terrible.  I did a Google search on "apple, banana, pineapple problem" and got a trivial math problem unrelated to this, then dozens of recipes, particularly smoothies.  Wikipedia has nothing on that title.  I urge you to try such a search, to see just how uninformative and misleading your title is for those who would like to find this problem on this site.

Comment: @David G. Stork:  How about  "A wonderfully sneaky little equation" as posed by the author at the very end of his essay in: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4/answer/Alon-Amit

Comment: @David G. Stork: Or how about: "Fruit Cocktail"? ; same title on an essay found in: https://www.futilitycloset.com/ (addressing this problem).

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi.  All these titles are absolutely terrible.  Absolutely terrible.  There are a million "wonderfully sneaky little equations" in the world unrelated to this, and a search on "fruit cocktail" gives many dozens of hits unrelated to this problem.  Really, you simply must do better than this.  What if a question was titled "My favorite math problem"?  or "A cool, unintuitive math problem"?  or "Cars, bars, and stars"?  Equally useless.

Comment: Apparently, title selection was not so eclectic in the past: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182797/adding-fruit-together
Nevertheless; I propose changing the subject title to:
"Finding a solution to equation: a/(b+c) + b/(c+a) + c/(a+b) = 4; with a, b, c > 0; involves solving the elliptic curve y^2 = x^3 + 109 x^2 + 224 x ."

Comment: http://soundbible.com/mp3/Night_Sounds_-_Crickets-Lisa_Redfern-591005346.mp3

Comment: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1552008?p_p _auth =Yl7ojX4C